# Flash coding for typewriter effect

Tags: flash, effect

I am a complete amateur in Flash so I hope you can explain to me what is wrong with this coding. Thank you!

Here is the coding that is written on just one keyframe:

```
    var myString: String = "This is a\nTeSt.";
var myArray: Array = myString.split("");
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameLooper);
function frameLooper(event:Event):void {
if(myArray.length > 0) {
    welcomeTxt.appendText (myArray.shift());
}
else {
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameLooper)
}
```

}

Below is what is shown in the output panel repeatedly, probably for each letter that I want to display:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at WEBSITE_fla::MainTimeline/frameLooper()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. I took it and use it in Flash and it worked as expected. Double check that the instance name of the textfield is set to welcomeTxt. If your able to post a link to the fla I can take a look if your still having issues.